# Problem with AnythingSlider when only having one post

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm using AnythingSlider, but i get an error if i only have one slide item.

It gives me this error: *'base.$navLinks' is null or not an object*.
The problem should be on line 149 in my jquery.anythingslider.js file. Which is the 3rd row in this bit of code:

```
if (base.options.buildNavigation){
   base.$nav.find('.cur').removeClass('cur');
   $(base.$navLinks[page - 1]).addClass('cur');
};
```

Let me know if i need to paste the whole jquery.anythingslider.js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changing the offending line to:

```
(page > 1) && $(base.$navLinks[page - 1]).addClass('cur');
```

fixed that for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in the [latest version](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-1-4/).